# Trying to save Multi-Value Form on server for users to call up during another session

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, forms, session

been searching here for a while on how to save form information to be re-called later.

Here is my site: http://d3barb.com

The purpose is people fill out the 100+ fields in the form and it will generate numbers corresponding to the game Diablo 3. The formulas all work perfectly, and sometimes the cookie will save the information, but I'm trying to figure out a way to save the entire "page", so users can call them up during a different session.

I've tried for about 6 hours to get setCookie / getCookie functiond to create a cookie with all the values saved, but can't seem to get it to work. Even if it was working, it would only allow the user to load their last seission when re-visiting the site.

How I would like it perform:

1.) User inputs information for the form to calculate.

2.) User fills out a "name" text field and hits a "Save" button (I have these on my test page, but don't want it live until its working), which will save the values on my server containing all the form information as they've entered it.

3.) The next time that User visits the page, they would hit "Load" to call up a previous session.

I'd like to avoid user-account log-ins, so if possible I'd like the server to save the sessions by IP address & user submitted session name, something like: 142.105.103.125.fire crusader

Currently, the page is html with js calculating everything. I can convert it php for server interaction, but if there is another way, I'm all ears.

I'm not looking for handouts, so any links to tutorials would be greatly appreciated. If someone has done something similar to this and wouldn't mind sharing that page or code with me, I can do my best to frankenstein it for my page. (pretty much how I do all my websites haha!)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried/considered HTML 5 local storage?
http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-web-storage/
should get you started :)